# how to detect which device is group owner from list of peers?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to know if there is already any group owner in the list of peers returned by onPeerListAvailable() in wifidirect ?
Is there any way of knowing it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDevice.html#isGroupOwner%28%29

```
public boolean isGroupOwner ()
Added in API level 14

Returns true if the device is a group owner
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to have the connection established in order to know who is the group owner.

And then if you are group owner you get the information when you get onConnectionInfoAvailable called, and to get it called you should call requestConnectionInfo() once you get event informing that you are indeed connected.

From client side, you would simply get the ip-address of the Group owner,

Comment: yes, i got your point, but i want all the devices to connect to server only.In order to do that i want to give all the peer devices information that which among the peer list is a server..how can i do that?

Comment: @Furious Nobody can know who the Group Owner is without actually connecting to the group. Hence, it is not possible to communicate to the devices which are not part of the group (i.e. not connected) who the group owner is except you do it manually...

Comment: its simple in this case. As you want only to contact to the one device. Then my suggestion is: In the Group owner, call Greatecroup funciton from the API to make a group in it, add local service to advertise your service, and start peer discovery (needed to make your service advertisement visible to other devices).

Comment: Then on clients, simply do peer discovery, and once you see any peer, do service discovery, and see that you find the device advertising your own service. Then just connect to it. The connecting party should now be client & the group owner as it created the group in beginning is the group owner. Any additional connection will of course not change the group owner..

Comment: Do note that, in this case as the connections are initiated from the clients, all acceptance dialogs are shown in group owner side.